# Laravel routes showing 404 when run in windows but ok when run in docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, routes, wsl-2

I have a laravel project which I cloned from Bitbucket which I think is intended to be run in docker. Problem is, when I run it in docker, the pages load very slowly (like 3-5 minutes load speed). I made some research and decided to run it in windows (php artisan serve). It is loading faster now but the new problem is that all the routes keep showing as 404 - route not found.

I made some other research and I've tried:

1. Checking the route list (route:list)
2. Clearing the route cache
3. Clearing the config cache
4. Making slight changes to the code to see if the error changes
5. Tried to run the project in ubuntu in WSL2 but found I couldn't connect to XAMPP mysql from WSL2

None of these changed the error or fixed the problem.

WEB.PHP FILE

```
<?php

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


Route::get('/search', [SearchController::class, 'getSearch'])->name('search');
```

INDEX.PHP FILE

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

.HTACCESS FILE

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Please, what do you think the problem might be - I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: FYI, I'm used docker for more than five years now. But I never encountered page slowness. (There will be a significant delay since WSL is on Windows. But I don't think it will make a noticeable impact )

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - It's a bit surprising to me as I've run multiple projects on docker and never experienced this issue. Although, the database size is nearly 500mb so I don't know it this is part of the reasons it is slow.